# How can I use reCAPTCHA in my single commercial product

Tags: recaptcha

I can't understand how can I integrate reCAPTCHA in a single commercial product, is there any idea? As far as I know It should be activated for each single domain with API Key, but the single product can't do that automatically.
If there isn't any way is there any totally freedom (not GPL) solutions for a commercial product?